# splitting this string, whats wrong with my code?

Tags: java, string, split

This is a beginner course so there is probably an easier method, but can someone look at my code and tell me why it wont split the last string and print it? I split it successfully the first two times.

////////////////////////////////////
        String line = "user=Abby&topic=0&message=I+cannot+wait+for+the+snow.";

```
    String[] parts = line.split("&"); //split&
    String part1 = parts[0]; // user=Abby 
    String part2 = parts[1];//  topic=0
    String part3 = parts[2];//  message=I+cannotwaitforthesnow

    String[] user = part1.split("=");  //Split USER=Abby
    String user1 = user[0]; // user
    String user2 = user[1]; //  Abby

    String[] topic = part2.split("=");  //split topi=0
    String topic1 = topic[0]; // Topic
    String topic2 = topic[1]; // 0

    String[] text = part3.split("="); //split message=iasd
    String text1 = text[0]; // message
    String text2 = text[1]; // I+cannot+wait+for+the+snow


    String[] message = text2.split("+"); //split I+cannot+wait+for+the+snow.
    String message1 = message[0];//I
    String message2 = message[1];//cannot
    String message3 = message[2];//wait
    String message4 = message[3];//for
    String message5 = message[4];//the
    String message6 = message[5];//snow.


    output.println("This is the input that the client sent: ");

    System.out.println(user2);
    System.out.println(topic1 + topic2);
    System.out.println(message1 + message2 + message3 + message4 + message5 + message6);
```

//////////////////////

so it successfully works, but when i added the split for message at the end it did not split and print, just blank. an anyone tell me why?

thanks for any help

Comment: Java is not JavaScript.

Answer (score 4):

The Javadocs say

> public String[] split(String regex)
>
> Splits this string around matches
> of the given regular expression.

And + is a reserved character in regex so you need to escape it.

Answer (score 0):

You should try

```
String[] message = text2.split("\\+");
```

In java '+' is a reserved character, you should escape it with '\' in order to use it in this context

Comment: '+' is a reserved character in Regex, not in Java :)